# Spring MVC mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mapping

I made a really simple app but running into error.

**My Web.XML**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
       <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Servlet-context.XML**

```
<beans:bean name="newpage.jsp" class="com.project.NewHello.resultsController"/>

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>


<context:component-scan base-package="com.project.NewHello" />
```

**newpageController.java**

```
 package com.project.NewHello;


 import java.util.Locale;

 import org.springframework.ui.Model;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

  public class newpageController {


public String newpage(Locale locale, Model model) {

    return "newpage";
}
  }



**Some of Error lines:**
```

It does not find the newpage.jsp file, and in console shows, 
WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:NewHello' did not find a matching property.

Thanks

Comment: What is the actual content of spring-servlet.xml? namespace declarations, `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` etc.

Comment: Hi Boris, I have a root-context.xml file which its content is as following:                                                         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
 
 
  
</beans>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by looking at your configuration and naming of classes it looks like your not as familiar with canonical Java.

For example your package names (`NewHello`) should generally be lower case:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.project.newhello" />
```

There are whole bunch of interesting oddities. Like naming the bean after a JSP file (which I'm worried you will think that it will use that JSP file).

*What I highly recommend you do is look at one of the following quick start projects that will do some scaffolding for you*:

- [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo/)
- [AppFuse Spring MVC](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Using+Spring+MVC)
- [Spring Maven Archetype](https://github.com/kolorobot/spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype)

Use one of the above projects to create your initial project plus you can see what the standard practices are in those projects (as there is a Spring and Java way of doing things).

Once you get comfortable you can see a more complete fully functioning Spring MVC project by the people who make Spring:

[Spring Greenhouse](https://github.com/SpringSource/greenhouse)

Comment: To have a quick configured project, you can also use Spring Tool Suite (STS) : New > Spring Template Project > Spring MVC Project.